# Moment of inertia of a rolling cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

Here is the question:

> "A rigid body with a cylindrical cross-section is released from the top of a $30^{\text{o}}$ incline. It rolls $10.0 \, \text{m}$ to the bottom in $2.60 \text{s}$. Find the moment of inertia of the body in terms of its mass $m$ and radius $r$."

What I don't quite understand is why you couldn't just use the normal formula for the moment of inertia for a solid cylinder rotating around its cylindrical axis. Then it would be $0.5 m r^{2}$. But using the formula for an object rolling down the incline without slipping gives $0.66 m r^{2}$. I don't understand conceptually why it's different.

Comment: Does the cylinder have a uniform density?   Is it solid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula $I=\frac{1}{2}mr^2$ for the [moment of inertia
of a solid cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#Moments_of_inertia) is only valid, if its density is homogeneous.
But it is not valid anymore, if the density varies with radius.

For example:
If its mass is concentrated near the outer edge,
then the moment of inertia is closer to $mr^2$.
And if its mass is concentrated near the axis,
then the moment of inertia is closer to $0$.